# Secure remote sqlbuddy in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I've added sqlbuddy on my nginx server for remote management of my db. To that I've added .htaccess and password protection. However if I click on cancel in the authentication prompt / window I can still access the login for sqlbuddy. I can login and see a few parts of the UI. If I access the browser source I can see more data. How do I stop this? What's the best setup for this in nginx?

This is nginx conf:

```
        location /sqlbuddy {
            auth_basic "Administrator Login";
            auth_basic_user_file /opt/nginx/html/sqlbuddy/.htpasswd;
    }
```